# What is the best approach in implementing Ruby classes in this example?

Tags: ruby

I have a class that creates an object called a 'session'.  When an instance of this class is created, one of its attributes (a datetime) must be updated every 30 seconds or so or I want to destroy the session either literally or with an instance variable.

I created a class variable array to contain time based information about created instances, and I'm hoping to allow another 'monitor' class to loop through this array on a variable time slice and 'expire' or destroy session instances.

1. How should my session and monitor classes best interact? Should one be a subclass of the other?
2. How can I make sure that the session class and monitor don't collide with one another as they access data about the sessions in the session class variable?

Comment: write it all in one class. refactor as needed.

Comment: Ruby is extremely flexible, so there are numerous ways this could be implemented. The "best approach" depends entirely on what your application is. Unfortunately you haven't given us any code or any concrete idea of how these objects will be used, so I don't see how anyone could give you a clear answer.